# How can display images in a uitable cell efficiently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Currently I have 2 ways of displaying images in a cell, which way will help to table run smoothly, I'll use lazytable later? In each cell should the buttons be given a setimage or is adding an imageview with a set image just as good? Also in the first method I have to scale each image dynamically. Thank you!

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:"png image from url"];

[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];


/// Or


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:"png image from url"];

UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

[button2 addSubview:imageView2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button has an image property, why adding an image view to the button, its recommended to use approach 1

Comment: I did that because because I wouldn't have to rescale/resize the image. With a setimage, I have to resize it to a certain width and height first but I guess that doesn't matter, thanks